# How to replace every gif images in the page for another image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, gif

I'd like to know how can I replace every .gif images in a page for an image url that I already have. I've looked after many solutions but none could help me.

Edit: Removed the old code since it was causing some confusion

So does anybody knows how to do this? JS pure would be better since I can't get jQuery working properly with Tampermonkey.

Edit 2: Managed to get another code sort of working, but it doesn't replaces the image url, just adds to it.

```
    var theImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for(i=0; i<theImages.length; i++) {
        if(theImages[i].src.indexOf('.gif') != -1) {
        theImages[i].src = ('imageurl.jpg')}
}
```

Comment: I just ran your most recent code (its hard when you keep changing it XD) and it seems to work. theImages[i].src = ('imageurl.jpg') will completely change the url, it won't append to it.

Comment: Oh, yes, it was my fault. This code was actually deactivated on tampermonkey, an old one was activated. Thanks to everybody that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working using the following script:

```
var theImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(i=0; i<theImages.length; i++) {
    if(theImages[i].src.indexOf('.gif') != -1) {
    theImages[i].src = ('imageurl.jpg')}
}
```

Thanks to everybody that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line `var image_png_src = image_png_src.replace(".gif", "image.jpg");`. `image_png_src` is not yet defined but you try to call a replace property. Any way you probably wanted to use `image_gif_src` instead.

```
var image_png_src = image_gif_src.replace(".gif", "image.jpg");
```

Comment: He also needs to change "image.jpg" to just ".jpg" or else he would turn my_pic.gif into my_picimage.jpg, which I dont believe is his intention.

Comment: I actually took the code as a base, but I think it's not suitable for what I'm trying to do. I'll remove it from the post since it seems to be causing some confusion.

Comment: @Gus a question like this without any code will probably get closed as not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your images have the same name, and you just want to change the extention, your code is almost right, you just made a small mistake. Here is the correct version:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image_gif_src = images[i].src;
    var image_png_src = image_gif_src.replace(".gif", ".jpg");
    images[i].src = image_png_src;
}
```

Notice how `image_png_src.replace` in the second line of the for loop has been replaced with `image_gif_src.replace`? You were trying to do a replace on the wrong variable. Also, I changed `"image.jpg"` in your original example to just `".jpg"` because I'm assuming you only mean to change the extention, not append the word "image" onto the end of whatever image you're changing.

If you want to change every gif to some other image, not just change the extention, this code would do it:

```
images[i].src = image_png_src;

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if( images[i].src.indexOf(".gif") > -1){
             images[i].src = "New Image.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery approach

```
$("img").each(function(){
$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(".gif", ".jpg"));
});
```

fyi, to use jquery or other js libraries in Xmonkey,
simply add

`// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js`
in the `==UserScript==` header. In case of conflicts, turning on `jQuery.noConflict();` may help.